# C++ Python convert data from vector to ndarray

Tags: c++, python, boost, numpy

I am creating a C++ project which includes some python. I have used `boost::python` but now I am stuck. I have some data stored in a `std::vector`. The data should be send to python to do some calculations. The Python NumPy functions I use need the data in `ndarray` format, so I need a way to convert it. Since I want to do some more things with the results in C++ I want to convert the result back from `ndarray` to `std::vector`.

How can I convert `std::vector` to `ndarray` and vice versa? Can anyone post some sample code?
I know there is a lib called `boost.numpy` out there, but are there other ways, because I was not able to build this lib...

Can I use `boost::python::numeric` for the job? Can anyone provide sample code?

Is it possible without copying data?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are willing to use the [C Numpy API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html).

You should look at C/C++ `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` to create [brand new](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html#PyArray_SimpleNewFromData) ndarray in your c++ code.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924827/numpy-array-c-api) may help.