# Why i'm unable to copy PyArrayObject?

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-c-api

How i can copy existing PyArrayObject ?

I've read documentation from this link http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#creating-arrays

Also I've read this explanations:
[numpy array C api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924827/numpy-array-c-api/2925014#2925014)

[PyArray_SimpleNewFromData example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357115/pyarray-simplenewfromdata-example?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I've tried to use PyArray_CopyInto and PyArray_CopyAnyInto with same result (error).

This is my code:

```
void from_list(PyObject*i_list) {
int x=1;
temp = retrieve(PyList_GetItem(i_list, x)); //list have 3 elements of type PyArrayObject*
}

void retrieve(PyArrayObject* slice) {
  PyArrayObject*temp = CopyArray(slice);
}

PyArrayObject*CopyArray(PyArrayObject*obj) {
PyArrayObject*ret;
int nd = obj->nd;
int type_num = obj->descr->type_num;
unsigned char*data;
npy_intp dims[2];
dims[0] = obj->dimensions[0];
dims[1] = obj->dimensions[1];
data = malloc(dims[0]*dims[1] + 100); 
memcpy( data, (unsigned char*)obj->data, dims[0]*dims[1] );

printf("\n ready to do \n");

ret = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, dims, NPY_CHAR, (void*)data);  //python interpreter crashes 

printf("\n ready to return \n");
return ret;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Also, please, could you give me a link to implementations of all this function of type PyArraySomething.

Thank you.

Comment: *"...with same result (error)"*  When you have question about code that generates an error, always include the complete error message in the question.

Comment: problem is i don't know how retrieve it, i run this in python interpreter, and after line  printf("\n ready to do \n");  interpreter crashes

Comment: How does it crash?  Core dump?  SIGSEGV?  SIGILL? ....

Comment: "An unhandled win32 exception occured in python.exe [5556]"  if i try to debug it  "Unable attach to crashed process"

Comment: I think the 5556 is an error in trying to connect a JIT debugger and is masking the real problem.